# Any way to highlight pdf document for given words via Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, python-module

there are some keywords I am gotten before and I want to search on pdf document via python and highlight them. Is it viable with some library like pdfMiner?

Comment: If you're on a mac, it may be better to use AppleScript via osascript

Comment: nope, on linux machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read, highlight, save PDF programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605577/read-highlight-save-pdf-programmatically)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use 'PyMuPDF' library.
pip install PyMuPDF.

Then use the following code,

```
import fitz

### READ IN PDF

doc = fitz.open(r"D:\XXXX\XXX.pdf")
page = doc[0]

text = "Amey"
text_instances = page.searchFor(text)

### HIGHLIGHT

for inst in text_instances:
    print(inst, type(inst))
    highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(inst)


### OUTPUT

doc.save(r"D:\XXXX\XXX.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```