# How to extract text and text coordinates from a PDF file?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I want to extract all the text boxes and text box coordinates from a PDF file with PDFMiner.

Many other Stack Overflow posts address how to extract all text in an ordered fashion, but how can I do the intermediate step of getting the text and text locations?

Given a PDF file, output should look something like:

```
489, 41,  "Signature"
500, 52,  "b"
630, 202, "a_g_i_r"
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/25248140/1709587, a dupe that was posted a few months after this one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Full disclosure, I am one of the maintainers of [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six). It is a community-maintained version of pdfminer for python 3.

Nowadays, pdfminer.six has multiple API's to extract text and information from a PDF. For programmatically extracting information I would advice to use `extract_pages()`. This allows you to inspect all of the elements on a page, ordered in a meaningful hierarchy created by the layout algorithm.

The following example is a pythonic way of showing all the elements in the hierachy. It uses the [simple1.pdf](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/master/samples/simple1.pdf) from the samples directory of pdfminer.six.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Any

from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages


def show_ltitem_hierarchy(o: Any, depth=0):
    """Show location and text of LTItem and all its descendants"""
    if depth == 0:
        print('element                        x1  y1  x2  y2   text')
        print('------------------------------ --- --- --- ---- -----')

    print(
        f'{get_indented_name(o, depth):<30.30s} '
        f'{get_optional_bbox(o)} '
        f'{get_optional_text(o)}'
    )

    if isinstance(o, Iterable):
        for i in o:
            show_ltitem_hierarchy(i, depth=depth + 1)


def get_indented_name(o: Any, depth: int) -> str:
    """Indented name of LTItem"""
    return '  ' * depth + o.__class__.__name__


def get_optional_bbox(o: Any) -> str:
    """Bounding box of LTItem if available, otherwise empty string"""
    if hasattr(o, 'bbox'):
        return ''.join(f'{i:<4.0f}' for i in o.bbox)
    return ''


def get_optional_text(o: Any) -> str:
    """Text of LTItem if available, otherwise empty string"""
    if hasattr(o, 'get_text'):
        return o.get_text().strip()
    return ''


path = Path('~/Downloads/simple1.pdf').expanduser()

pages = extract_pages(path)
show_ltitem_hierarchy(pages)
```

The output shows the different elements in the hierarchy. The bounding box for each. And the text that this element contains.

```
element                        x1  y1  x2  y2   text
------------------------------ --- --- --- ---- -----
generator                       
  LTPage                       0   0   612 792  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        100 695 161 719  Hello
      LTTextLineHorizontal     100 695 161 719  Hello
        LTChar                 100 695 117 719  H
        LTChar                 117 695 131 719  e
        LTChar                 131 695 136 719  l
        LTChar                 136 695 141 719  l
        LTChar                 141 695 155 719  o
        LTChar                 155 695 161 719  
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        261 695 324 719  World
      LTTextLineHorizontal     261 695 324 719  World
        LTChar                 261 695 284 719  W
        LTChar                 284 695 297 719  o
        LTChar                 297 695 305 719  r
        LTChar                 305 695 311 719  l
        LTChar                 311 695 324 719  d
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        100 595 161 619  Hello
      LTTextLineHorizontal     100 595 161 619  Hello
        LTChar                 100 595 117 619  H
        LTChar                 117 595 131 619  e
        LTChar                 131 595 136 619  l
        LTChar                 136 595 141 619  l
        LTChar                 141 595 155 619  o
        LTChar                 155 595 161 619  
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        261 595 324 619  World
      LTTextLineHorizontal     261 595 324 619  World
        LTChar                 261 595 284 619  W
        LTChar                 284 595 297 619  o
        LTChar                 297 595 305 619  r
        LTChar                 305 595 311 619  l
        LTChar                 311 595 324 619  d
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        100 495 211 519  H e l l o
      LTTextLineHorizontal     100 495 211 519  H e l l o
        LTChar                 100 495 117 519  H
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 127 495 141 519  e
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 151 495 156 519  l
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 166 495 171 519  l
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 181 495 195 519  o
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 205 495 211 519  
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        321 495 424 519  W o r l d
      LTTextLineHorizontal     321 495 424 519  W o r l d
        LTChar                 321 495 344 519  W
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 354 495 367 519  o
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 377 495 385 519  r
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 395 495 401 519  l
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 411 495 424 519  d
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        100 395 211 419  H e l l o
      LTTextLineHorizontal     100 395 211 419  H e l l o
        LTChar                 100 395 117 419  H
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 127 395 141 419  e
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 151 395 156 419  l
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 166 395 171 419  l
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 181 395 195 419  o
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 205 395 211 419  
        LTAnno                  
    LTTextBoxHorizontal        321 395 424 419  W o r l d
      LTTextLineHorizontal     321 395 424 419  W o r l d
        LTChar                 321 395 344 419  W
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 354 395 367 419  o
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 377 395 385 419  r
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 395 395 401 419  l
        LTAnno                  
        LTChar                 410 395 424 419  d
        LTAnno
```

(Similar answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962316/4054971),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962482/4054971) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962459/4054971)
, I'll try to keep them in sync.)

Comment: that's absolutely beautiful, amazing!

Comment: Is there any chance pdfminer will support grouping `LTChar` in `LTFigure` into `LTTextBox` es in the future?

Comment: The link for the pdf is not correct. It takes me to another web page. Can you kindly post the right link for the PDF? Thanks

Comment: Done. Now it links the PDF directly.

Comment: Thanks for this code it is a life saver! Any way it can be adjusted to display the page number? I have a muti page PDF with similar items in each page and similar coordinates so it's difficult to know the text belongs to which page since all have the same coordinates? I'm only interested in LTTextBoxHorizontal...thanks so much! :-)

Answer (score 59):

Here's a copy-and-paste-ready example that lists the top-left corners of every block of text in a PDF, and which I think should work for any PDF that doesn't include "Form XObjects" that have text in them:

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

fp = open('yourpdf.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for page in pages:
    print('Processing next page...')
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for lobj in layout:
        if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
            x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
            print('At %r is text: %s' % ((x, y), text))
```

The code above is based upon the [Performing Layout Analysis](https://pdfminer-docs.readthedocs.io/programming.html#performing-layout-analysis) example in the PDFMiner docs, plus the examples by pnj (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22898159/1709587) and Matt Swain (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25262470/1709587). There are a couple of changes I've made from these previous examples:

- I use `PDFPage.get_pages()`, which is a shorthand for creating a document, checking it `is_extractable`, and passing it to `PDFPage.create_pages()`
- I don't bother handling `LTFigure`s, since PDFMiner is currently incapable of cleanly handling text inside them anyway.

`LAParams` lets you set some parameters that control how individual characters in the PDF get magically grouped into lines and textboxes by PDFMiner. If you're surprised that such grouping is a thing that needs to happen at all, it's justified in the [pdf2txt docs](https://pdfminer-docs.readthedocs.io/pdfminer_index.html#pdf2txt-py):

> In an actual PDF file, text portions might be split into several chunks in the middle of its running, depending on the authoring software. Therefore, text extraction needs to splice text chunks.

`LAParams`'s parameters are, like most of PDFMiner, undocumented, but you can see them [in the source code](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/20181108/pdfminer/layout.py#L34-L51) or by calling `help(LAParams)` at your Python shell. The meaning of *some* of the parameters is given at https://pdfminer-docs.readthedocs.io/pdfminer_index.html#pdf2txt-py since they can also be passed as arguments to `pdf2text` at the command line.

The `layout` object above is an `LTPage`, which is an iterable of "layout objects". Each of these layout objects can be one of the following types...

- `LTTextBox`
- `LTFigure`
- `LTImage`
- `LTLine`
- `LTRect`

... or their subclasses. (In particular, your textboxes will probably all be `LTTextBoxHorizontal`s.)

More detail of the structure of an `LTPage` is shown by this image from the docs:

[image: Tree diagram of the structure of an <code>LTPage</code>. Of relevance to this answer: it shows that an <code>LTPage</code> contains the 5 types listed above, and that an <code>LTTextBox</code> contains <code>LTTextLine</code>s plus unspecified other stuff, and that an <code>LTTextLine</code> contains <code>LTChar</code>s, <code>LTAnno</code>s, <code>LTText</code>s, and unspecified other stuff.]

Each of the types above has a `.bbox` property that holds a (*x0*, *y0*, *x1*, *y1*) tuple containing the coordinates of the left, bottom, right, and top of the object respectively. The y-coordinates are given as the distance from the *bottom* of the page. If it's more convenient for you to work with the y-axis going from top to bottom instead, you can subtract them from the height of the page's `.mediabox`:

```
x0, y0_orig, x1, y1_orig = some_lobj.bbox
y0 = page.mediabox[3] - y1_orig
y1 = page.mediabox[3] - y0_orig
```

In addition to a `bbox`, `LTTextBox`es also have a `.get_text()` method, shown above, that returns their text content as a string. Note that each `LTTextBox` is a collection of `LTChar`s (characters explicitly drawn by the PDF, with a `bbox`) and `LTAnno`s (extra spaces that PDFMiner adds to the string representation of the text box's content based upon the characters being drawn a long way apart; these have no `bbox`).

The code example at the beginning of this answer combined these two properties to show the coordinates of each block of text.

Finally, it's worth noting that, *unlike* the other Stack Overflow answers cited above, I don't bother recursing into `LTFigure`s. Although `LTFigure`s can contain text, PDFMiner doesn't seem capable of grouping that text into `LTTextBox`es (you can try yourself on the example PDF from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27104504/1709587) and instead produces an `LTFigure` that directly contains `LTChar` objects. You could, in principle, figure out how to piece these together into a string, but PDFMiner (as of version 20181108) can't do it for you.

Hopefully, though, the PDFs you need to parse don't use Form XObjects with text in them, and so this caveat won't apply to you.

Comment: Hi I have an Invoice format pdf. Can I give the location of the text to be extracted and it extracts those text fields?

Comment: Is this library useful if i already have coordinates and wants to fetch text using it

Comment: The Y coordinate generated by this code are off in about 5 pixels

Comment: @EliaWeiss what do you mean? "Off" relative to what alternative way of calculating/defining the y-coordinate?

Comment: relative to the image produce from the pdf, the other alternative is OCR - e.g. if I can find the text in the pdf, I would prefer it over the OCR

Comment: @EliaWeiss But how are you deciding exactly where the top-left corner of a given text box is when inspecting that image? There's no objectively correct answer since it depends on how much margin you put around the text. Select some text in this comment, for instance; observe that the blue text selection background your browser/OS draws extends beyond the highest pixel of any character (likely by _more than 5 pixels_) - so when computing the position of the text, where do we measure to? It's somewhat arbitrary. Different tools can reasonably disagree by 5 pixels without either being wrong.

Comment: @EliaWeiss If you've got an example where the y coordinates of `LTTextBox`es pdfminer comes up with are clearly perverse - e.g. where the box pdfminer draws truncates some of the glyphs of the text, or where the margins above and below the text are asymmetrical - it might be worth reporting that as a bug *in pdfminer*, but it's not clear to me whether you've even encountered such a case or merely an instance of reasonable disagreement between tools about how much margin to leave when synthesising boxes around text. But even then, the code *in this answer* wouldn't be the problem, surely?

Answer (score 50):

Newlines are converted to underscores in final output. This is the minimal working solution that I found.

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
import pdfminer

# Open a PDF file.
fp = open('/Users/me/Downloads/test.pdf', 'rb')

# Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
parser = PDFParser(fp)

# Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
# Password for initialization as 2nd parameter
document = PDFDocument(parser)

# Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
if not document.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

# Create a PDF resource manager object that stores shared resources.
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

# Create a PDF device object.
device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)

# BEGIN LAYOUT ANALYSIS
# Set parameters for analysis.
laparams = LAParams()

# Create a PDF page aggregator object.
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

# Create a PDF interpreter object.
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

def parse_obj(lt_objs):

    # loop over the object list
    for obj in lt_objs:

        # if it's a textbox, print text and location
        if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
            print "%6d, %6d, %s" % (obj.bbox[0], obj.bbox[1], obj.get_text().replace('\n', '_'))

        # if it's a container, recurse
        elif isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTFigure):
            parse_obj(obj._objs)

# loop over all pages in the document
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):

    # read the page into a layout object
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()

    # extract text from this object
    parse_obj(layout._objs)
```

Comment: I've left my own answer that tweaks this in a couple of ways. The first `device` you create here you never use, and the initial cruft setting up the parse can be shortened with `get_pages`. I'm particularly curious to know: did you ever find a case in which recursing into `LTFigure`s worked? My own experimentation suggests to me that text inside them does *not* get grouped into textbox objects by PDFMiner, and that therefore your recursion into them here will never work.

Comment: Anyone arriving from Google will almost certainly want the newest answer at the bottom which is extremely elegant https://stackoverflow.com/a/69151177/5125264

Answer (score 1):

This works easily with pymupdf https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app1.html

```
import fitz
with fitz.open(path_to_pdf_file) as document:
    words_dict = {}
    for page_number, page in enumerate(document):
        words = page.get_text("words")
        words_dict[page_number] = words
```

Comment: did not work for me unfortunately