# How does one obtain the location of text in a PDF with PDFMiner?

Tags: python, pdf, position, pdfminer

PDFMiner's documentation says:

> PDFMiner allows one to obtain the exact location of text in a page

However, I have not been able to find how to do this. PDFMiner's 'documentation' is rather sparse, so I have not understood how to do this.

Answer (score 26):

You are looking for the `bbox` property on every layout object. There is a little bit of information on [how to parse the layout hierarchy](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/programming.html) in the PDFMiner documentation, but it doesn't cover everything.

Here's an example:

```
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine, LTFigure


def parse_layout(layout):
    """Function to recursively parse the layout tree."""
    for lt_obj in layout:
        print(lt_obj.__class__.__name__)
        print(lt_obj.bbox)
        if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
            print(lt_obj.get_text())
        elif isinstance(lt_obj, LTFigure):
            parse_layout(lt_obj)  # Recursive


fp = open('example.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    parse_layout(layout)
```

If you are interested in the location of individual `LTChar` objects, you can recursively parse into the child layout objects of `LTTextBox` and `LTTextLine` just like what is done with `LTFigure` in the above example.

Comment: 1) Could you explain what LAParams() does, please?
2) Isn't it more pythonic to try to get text and then try to recurse rather than using isinstance?

Comment: Aren't there other types of containers other than LTFigure?

Comment: LAParams contains the parameters used for the layout analysis that merges characters into words and lines based on their locations. You can pass initialization parameters like line_overlap, char_margin, line_margin, word_margin, boxes_flow, detect_vertical. See PDFMiner docs for explanation and default values.

Comment: Other than `LTFigure` there's also `LTTextBox` that contains `LTTextLine` which in turn contains `LTChar` and `LTAnno`. The [PDFMiner docs](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/programming.html) have a diagram of the hierarchy.

Comment: Things seem to work without passing LAParams, why are they needed?
Isn't it more Pythonic to EAFP rather then use isinstance?

Comment: `LAParams` is really just a way to modify the parameters used by the layout analyser. It's good practice to pass to `PDFPageAggregator` even if you just use the default parameters, because otherwise some of the layout analysis may not be performed. You probably can make my `parse_layout` function more pythonic. Every `LT*` object should be iterable even if it doesn't have any children, so the `LTFigure` isinstance check is probably unnecessary. Similarly, you could just attempt `get_text()` for all and catch the failure if it's not implemented on that `LT*` object.

Comment: Is there any way to parse just first LTTextBox of each page?(actually I want the box header )

Comment: What's your basis for thinking that recursing into `LTFigure`s like this works? Over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360415/1709587, I claim it's broken because an `LTFigure` cannot contain an `LTTextBox`... but if I'm wrong, I'd appreciate you proving me so.

Comment: Rather using `LTTextBox`, is there another parameter that will just find coordinates for individual words?