# PDF miner, bad new line detection

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am using this code to get text data from PDF :

```
def pdf_to_txt(path):    
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()
    layout = LAParams(all_texts=True)
    device = TextConverter(manager, retstr, laparams=layout)
    filepath = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(filepath, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = retstr.getvalue()
    filepath.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

In my PDF file i have in line separator TAB example(i believe thats TAB because two words are in same column cell and separator have more than one whitespace):
    `Hello    this is`

PDF miner is converting this line to :

```
    Hello
    this is
```

Expected output:

```
Hello this is
```

Does anyone have an idea how to set additional separator to this PDFminer to avoid creating new lines?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say that that's a bug, so file a bug report. If you really want to fix this yourself, you'd have to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug inside one of PDF's to solve it I justed coordinates of lines to compare them, more info you can find here:[How to extract text and text coordinates from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898145/how-to-extract-text-and-text-coordinates-from-a-pdf-file/22898159#22898159)