# How extract text geometry using PyPDF2?

Tags: pypdf

I have `pdf` documents.
And it's clear to me how to extract text from it.

I need to extract not only text but also coordinates associated with this text.

It's my code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
pdf_path = 'docs/doc_3.pdf'
pdf = PdfReader(pdf_path)
page_1_object = pdf.getPage(1)
page_1_object.extractText().split("\n")
```

The result is:

```
['Creating value for all stakeholders',
 'Anglo\xa0American is re-imagining mining to improve people’s lives.']
```

I need geometries associated with extracted paragraphs.
Might be something like this for example:

```
['Creating value for all stakeholders', [1,2,3,4,]]
 'Anglo\xa0American is re-imagining mining to improve people’s lives.', [7,8,9,10]]
```

How I can accomplish it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that ability is not a PyPDF2 feature, it has the ability for parsing the content as you show `extractText()` but does not hold the separate glyph xy positions nor output the lines coordinates.

There are other means in python to extract a single or multiple groups of letters that form words.

Using shell commands such as poppler from / in conjunction with a text "word" from PyPDF2 is possible, however the norm would be to run with another Py PDF Lib such as PyMuPDF and here is such an article, https://pyquestions.com/find-text-position-in-pdf-file for highlighting with PyMuPDF input.

The most common means to your goal is probably as described here [How to extract text and text coordinates from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898145/how-to-extract-text-and-text-coordinates-from-a-pdf-file)