# How to detect drawings and get their size from a pdf using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pymupdf, pdfpages

Basically I want to detect and get the bounding box of the figures or drawings which are in pdf using python, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap3A0.png) As per the image I just want the bounding box of the figure right below the question, but it also detects the "-" present in the options.

So I tried using the fitz_page.get_drawings() method from fitz library and it helps in replicating the images on another pdf file, but doesn't help in differentiating when the first figure ends and the second starts. I just want the x-y coordinates of the bounding box for each figure separately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898145/how-to-extract-text-and-text-coordinates-from-a-pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PyMuPDF currently returns information about boundaries of individual figures, though we have some internal code that might allow this in the next release.

Comment: Apologies, this comment rather overstated what our internal code can do - it's just a script that looks for overlapping paths.

For more information, please see: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/2247